# Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Ziaullah\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath

Tags: selenium, firefox, virtual-reality, geckodriver

I am using Firefox Quantum 59.0 (64-bit), on Windows 7 64 bit,

When I executed my test case in Eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
with geckodriver.exe version 0.20.0 release date 2018-03-08 both (with 32 bit and 64 bit), then following occurs in Eclipse console

Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Ziaullah\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath

JavaScript warning: https://my.bepms.com/ExternalLibrary/DateRangePicker-v2.1.17/moment.min.js, line 6: unreachable code after return statement

following is the line which caused the error:
wd.findElement(By.xpath("//p//button[text()='Never Show Again']")).click();

following are the firefox driver settings:
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\geckodriver.exe");
wd = new FirefoxDriver();

This test successfully executed on 
IE Version 11.0.9600.18952 64 bit
Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 64 bit

Comment: `Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Ziaullah\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath` is a _INFO_ log and you can ignore it. Update the question with your exact code block & error stack trace.

Comment: I found the same issue and it's resolved by using old gecko driver which is V0.19.1.

Answer (score -1):

quick fix is create empty file C:\Users\Ziaullah\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath and then it will not show this exception.